# USACO Training milking time (longest non-milking time) - java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with Usaco training gate's milking time problem (aka milk2). My code works for the first few problems, but then doesn't work for one of the cases.

The problem is here:http://jeremiahflaga.blogspot.com/2011/09/milking-cows-programming-problem-from.html

The case that doesn't work is: [1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6] [7, 8] [9, 10] [11, 12] [13, 14] [15, 16] [17, 18] [19, 20] [1, 20]

I think it is because of the last [1, 20], and it makes my code not work as I don't think I'm managing the merging correctly, but I've tried for some time and ended up making the code worse.

```
    import java.io.*;import java.util.*;

public class milk2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("milk2in.txt"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("milk2.out"));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        int N = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        String line = "";
        int milkInterval = 0;
        int largestMilkInterval = 0;
        int noMilkInterval = 0;
        int largestNoMilkInterval = 0;
        milkingTime[] times = new milkingTime[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            milkingTime mt = new milkingTime(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            times[i] = mt;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(times));
        for (int i = 0; i < times.length - 1; i++) {
            noMilkInterval = 0;
            if (times[i].getEnd() >= times[i + 1].getStart()) {
                if (times[i].getStart() > times[i + 1].getStart()) {
                    milkInterval += times[i + 1].getEnd() - times[i + 1].getStart();
                } else {
                    milkInterval += (times[i].getEnd() - times[i].getStart()) + (times[i + 1].getEnd() - times[i + 1].getStart());
                }
                System.out.println("Milk Interval: " + milkInterval);
            } else {
                milkInterval += (times[i].getEnd() - times[i].getStart());
                if (milkInterval > largestMilkInterval) {
                    largestMilkInterval = milkInterval;
                }
                milkInterval = 0;
                noMilkInterval += times[i + 1].getStart() - times[i].getEnd();
                System.out.println("No milk interval: " + noMilkInterval);
            }
            if (noMilkInterval > largestNoMilkInterval) {
                largestNoMilkInterval = noMilkInterval;
            }
            if (milkInterval > largestMilkInterval) {
                largestMilkInterval = milkInterval;
            }

        }
        if (times.length == 1) {
            largestMilkInterval = times[0].getEnd() - times[0].getStart();
            largestNoMilkInterval = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Largest Milk Interval: " + largestMilkInterval);
        System.out.println("Largest no milk Interval: " + largestNoMilkInterval);
        // pw.println(largestMilkInterval + " " + largestNoMilkInterval);
        // pw.close();
    }

}

class milkingTime {
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public milkingTime(int s, int e) {
        start = s;
        end = e;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Start: " + start + " End: " + end;
    }
}
```

I also wonder if my code is just completely wrong, and this is not the correct direction of solving this problem.

Comment: I'm afraid your solution is wrong. See the first nested `if()` in the main loop: `if (times[i].getEnd() >= times[i + 1].getStart()) { if (times[i].getStart() > times[i + 1].getStart()) {....} ...}` – for intervals `i` and `i+1`like `[999 1000] [0 1]` it will add 1000 to the interval's length instead of detecting a gap 998 long.

Comment: You should better do a standard sort on your array to order intervals by startTime. Then scan it and merge overlapping intervals. You can either put merged intervals into a new array or just shift items towards the array's beginnig to replace merged items with a result of merging. Finally scan the compacted array for a longest interval and for a longest gab between them.

Comment: Errr... I meant a longest gap, of course. :( Too late to edit the comment, though.

Comment: Oh, thank you that makes a lot of sense, I'll try that!

Comment: Please see my answer below - I have included the hints above in it, expanded them a bit and partially converted into a C code.

Comment: Unrelated, yet important: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase, and class names in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems wrong.

The main mistake is an assumption you apparently made, that you can find all important correlations between given intervals in a single pass along the table. Alas, the problem formulation makes *no guarantee* the intervals are given in any specific order. It even specifically mentions there are several 'farmers' milking – so their repective schedules may make a total input unordered when concatenated, even if each schedule is ordered. This is a case in your example data, which contains an ordered run of ten intervals

> [1, 2] [3, 4] ... [19, 20]

and then another single-interval run

> [1. 20]

which covers the former.

To handle that, I'd recommend sorting the data by a start time of intervals:

> [1, 2] [1, 20] [3, 4] ... [19, 20]

Every two intervals with the same start time overlap, and now they sit in a contiguous block of the array, so we can easily find them. Additionally, an `i`-th interval overlaps some further `k`-th interval (with `i` less than `k`) if, and only if, the `i`-th one ends at the same time or later than the `k`-th one starts.

This is how I would merge them:

```
    int curr = 0;    // the interval to receive a merge
    int next = 1;    // the interval to be possibly merged into current

    while (next < N)
    {
        if (times[curr].getEnd() >= times[next].getStart()) // overlapping?
        {
            times[curr].expandTo( times[next].getEnd() );   // merge to the current
        }
        else
        {
            ++ curr;                          // finished merging to current
            if (curr != next)                 // some items got merged
                times[curr] = times[next];    // shift further items to emptied space
        }
        ++ next;
    }
    newN = curr + 1;        // number of separate intervals after all merges
```

Thanks to prior sorting we know the `k`-th interval can't start before the `i`-th one if `i<k` so the single condition reliably indicates all overlaps.

Of course the `expandTo` method in the `milkingTime` class must increase the end time to cover the given value:

```
class milkingTime {

    .....

    public void expandTo(int targetTime)
    {
        if (getEnd() < targetTime) {
            setEnd(targetTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Now finding the longest interval and the longest gap is straight forward:

```
    int longestInterval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < newN; ++ i) {
        if (times[i].getLength() > longestInterval)
            longestInterval = times[i].getLength();
    }

    int longestGap = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < newN; ++ i) {
        int gap = times[i].getStart() - times[i - 1].getEnd();
        if (gap > longestGap)
            longestGap = gap;
    }
```